# make a html from mysql(php) database using pretty table module

Tags: python-3.x

```
import mysql.connector as dd
from prettytable import from_db_cursor

con = dd.connect(host = 'localhost',database='scores',user = 'root',password ='')
    
with con:
    
    cur = con.cursor()    
    cur.execute('SELECT * FROM game')   
    
    x = from_db_cursor(cur) 
    
print(x)
```

the result I get is :

```
+-------------+--------------------+------------------+--------------+
| game_rounds | rounds_won_by_user | rounds_won_by_PC | rounds_draws |
+-------------+--------------------+------------------+--------------+
|      1      |         0          |        0         |      1       |
|      1      |         0          |        1         |      0       |
+-------------+--------------------+------------------+--------------+
```

I want to display this table in a  html.
I searched on how to do it but couldn't find a way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this:

```
from prettytable import from_html_one

with open("data.html", "r") as fp: 
    html = fp.read()

x = from_html_one(html)
print(x)
```

or import from html table is supported. Please see the following example:

```
import sys
from prettytable import PrettyTable
from prettytable import from_html
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')

html_string='''<table>
<tr>
<th>number</th>
<th>Cloud number</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>IP address</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>server01</td>
<td>Server 01</td>
<td>172.16.0.1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2</td>
<td>server02</td>
<td>Server 02</td>
<td>172.16.0.2</td>
</tr>
</table>'''

table = from_html(html_string)
```

Table output format
Just like supporting multiple inputs, the output of tables also supports multiple formats. In the example above, we have used print to output, which is a common output method.

1,print

Print the form directly through print. The table printed in this way will have a border.

2. Output table in HTML format

Print (table. Get? html? String()) can print out a table with html tags.

In the above example, using print (table. Get ﹣ HTML ﹣ string()) will print out the following results:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th>number</th>
    <th>Cloud number</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>IP address</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>server01</td>
    <td>Server 01</td>
    <td>172.16.0.1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>server02</td>
    <td>Server 02</td>
    <td>172.16.0.2</td>
</tr>
```

Reference:https://programmer.help/blogs/python-uses-prettytable-to-output-beautiful-tables.html

Comment: I dont want to hardcode the html as the table could change with the data inserted to it